# How to get better results in water segmentation?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

this is my first computer vision project and I am still understanding the basics. I am using water segmentation dataset from kaggle and tried training the model with 1888 images. I wanted to perform semantic segmentation to segment the water parts from the images. The model that I used is U-net architecture. The model performs good on the test images and I am getting somewhat decent results, but when I try to get the prediction for a new image the result is very bad. I tried different pre-trained model but they perform worse. The model architecture is the following codes below, output images are also attached below. Does anyone know any better approach or what I am doing wrong here?

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Activation, MaxPool2D, Concatenate


def conv_block(input, num_filters):
    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)    
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)  #Not in the original network
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x


def encoder_block(input, num_filters):
    x = conv_block(input, num_filters)
    p = MaxPool2D((2, 2))(x)
    return x, p   


def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(input)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip_features])
    x = conv_block(x, num_filters)
    return x


def build_unet(input_shape, n_classes):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    s1, p1 = encoder_block(inputs, 64)
    s2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, 128)
    s3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, 256)
    s4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, 512)

    b1 = conv_block(p4, 1024) #Bridge

    d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 64)

    if n_classes == 1:  #Binary
      activation = 'sigmoid'
    else:
      activation = 'softmax'

    outputs = Conv2D(n_classes, 1, padding="same", activation=activation)(d4)  #Change the activation based on n_classes
    print(activation)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="U-Net")
    return model
```

```py
model = build_unet(input_shape, n_classes=1)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

This is the result on test data:
[image]

And this the result on new images:
[image]`

Comment: pictures please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have some pre-processing done on your test data that is not performed on the new images. Specifically, I would look into image normalization: In most image processing neural networks input images are normalized to have (roughly) zero mean and unit variance. If this kind of normalization is part of your training/evaluation code you must have the same normalization also for the new images before processing them by the trained U-net.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after normalizing the new images.